# Wait till command is completely finished in Bash

Tags: bash, cloudcaptain

I'm using a utility called Boxfuse, and the convert command does some processing which takes some time, and has several lines of output over the course of this processing.

I'm trying to save the very last word from the very last output to a variable. This works about half of the time. The other half it actually saves the last word of one of the earlier lines of output. My bash looks like so:

```
BFCONVERT=$(boxfuse convert MyApp:1.3.5)
AMI=${BFCONVERT##* }
echo $AMI
```

The full output from this command, across several lines and over a minute or so:

```
Boxfuse client v.1.19.12.1000 Copyright 2016 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved. Account: myname (First Last) 
Waiting for AWS to create an AMI for myname/MyApp:1.3.5 in aws-region-1 (this may take up to 50 seconds) ... 
AMI created in 02:51.972s in aws-region-1 -> ami-12345678
```

Sometimes my script echoes the last word from the first or second line rather than the very last word. How do I force it to wait until the command is finished?

Comment: It sounds as if `boxfuse` either writes some of its output to standard error or exits after it forks a child process that actually produces the output.

Comment: It does neither of those in the scenario above.

Comment: @AxelFontaine is it possible the command sometimes doesn't return the last two lines? It seems like about half of the time I run it I get my last name (from the first line) as the last word with no additional output.

Comment: @AxelFontaine the weird part is that if I put this command in a loop with a sleep it either succeeds on the first try or every iteration fails.

Comment: @RhodesianHunter Rerunning used to be a noop. We have rolled out a new version today that now outputs a message that includes the AMI ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works.

```
lastline=`echo $BFCONVERT | tail -1`
AMI=${lastline##* }
echo $AMI
```

Comment: That does not appear to have done the trick as I'm still occasionally getting results like "Last)"

Comment: How about putting sleep command just after your program runs and then above line. sleep 1m;

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue either, nor does looping until a successful response is returned.